# Good practice for controller actions when creating subdomains for different user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating subdomains for different user types and was wondering what is a good practice in doing so. I have user type `admin`, `editor` and `grader`, and their subdomains `admin.somesite.com`, `editor.somesite.com` and `grader.somesite.com`.

The problem on which I run into is how to model connection between controller action and certain user type. If I have the following for root for subdomain `admin`:

```
match '/' => 'supers#main_site', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'admin' }
```

And I have a model of `Article` which can be edited by `editor` and `admin`. I already implemented verification for `edit` action inside `ArticlesController` which checks if the logged-in user is `editor` or `admin`. If not, I transfer him to error site.

My question is do I need to limit somehow Article edits to specific domains like this:

```
match '/articles/:id/edit' => 'articles#edit', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'admin' }
match '/articles/:id/edit' => 'articles#edit', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'editor' }
```

Or it is enough to just navigate to article editing while I am already navigating inside that domain? So, if `editor` is already logged in on his domain `editor.somesite.com` and he clicks to edit article on his home page it will normally bring him to `editor.somesite.com/articles/:id/edit` and if `admin` does it, he will see `admin.somesite.com/articles/:id/edit`.

What would be a good practice with multiple subdomains and permissions? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. I was confused about this recently but at the end I decided just to use check of the domain request. I don't allow login to users to domains which is not theirs so if user who wants to access to content which is intended only for other domain users tries to do it, I just transfer him to login site. If can't login, he can't do anything. I am also curious about the other answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about best practices, but I can tell you a few things that I did in a similar situation.

If an application has subdomains, I think of each subdomain as being it's own application. For convenience, they might share the same Rails project and have access to the same models and assets. However, my mindset is that they are separate applications, which influenced the following decisions.

I did end up segmenting my routes. You can use the [`constraints`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) method to group your resources by user type. For example:

```
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
  # All the admin routes
end

constraints subdomain: 'editor' do
  # All the editor routes
end
```

This makes it really simple to determine who has access to what, and makes each individual route less complicated since you're not repeating `, constraints: { subdomain: <role> }` over and over. Essentially, what you're doing is saying, "Here are the routes in the admin application, here are the routes in the editor application."

The other thing I did was create specific controllers for each role. I resisted this initially, thinking that it wasn't difficult to figure out how each role related to each action. However, after splitting out role-specific controller, I was shocked at how much more simple each action became. The trade off is a few fairly complicated actions for many very simple methods.

There were project-specific rules that might have made my roles more complicated than yours, but these are some things I'd consider.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds right! So how did you handle generated path to model's actions? For example User model which can be edited by two types of users. Then I would need to type all these paths for creation of user, update of user etc under routes or? Or you made (for my case) `AdminUsersController` and `EditorUsersController` and put under routes for admin `resources :admin_users` and under routes for editor `resources :editor_users`? I hope you understand me :)

Comment: [`namespace` or `scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) to route to the correct set of controllers, and [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for avoiding specifying create/update, etc. routes for each resource.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's clear now what I need to do. So, basically I will create folders `User1`, `User2` and `User3` for my user types and  then for each of these folder I will create `UsersController` which is specific for that user type. Then I will do like this: `namespace :editor constraints subdomain: 'editor' do
  resources :users
end`. The same for other user types. Please confirm. You saved me with this!

Comment: Yep, so you'd have something like `app/controllers/editor/articles_controller.rb`.

Comment: Sorry for too many questions but I was just wobdering what did you do with ApplicationController? Did you also made separate controllers?

Comment: I did, but do what makes sense for your application.